# Intro to proof in real analysis 1

Tags: real-analysis

This is what I have to prove: For elements $x, y$ in an ordered field, if $0 < x < y$
then $y^{-1} < x^{-1}.$

My proof: $0 < x < y$ 
      multiply $x^{-1}$ on the left of both sides to get $x^{-1}0 < x^{-1}x < x^{-1}y $ 
                                                     $0 < 1 < x^{-1}y$ 
       then multiply $y^{-1}$ to the right of both sides to get $0y^{-1} < 1y^{-1} < x^{-1}yy^{-1}$ 
 
       And then we get $0 < y^{-1} < x^{-1}$.

Are there any problems with this proof?

Comment: By the looks of it, your proof is fine. The only improvement I could suggest is to use the slightly more technical terms of "pre" and "post" multiplying, rather than saying "multiplying on the left/right side".

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.

Comment: It is correct, but be aware this only wors because of $x,y > 0 \Leftrightarrow x^{-1}, y^{-1} > 0$.

Comment: Do I have to assume that x^-1 > 0 and y^-1 > 0 for the proof to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment by AlexR, the crucial part of the argument is to notice that because $x,y>0$ it follows that $x^{-1},y^{-1}>0$. Indeed, since $1>0$, and since $x\cdot x^{-1}=1$, it follows that $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are either both positive or both negative, and the claim follows.

Now the argument is simply multiplying the inequality $0<x<y$ by the positive element $x^{-1}y^{-1}$ (on the left or on the right, it doesn't matter since any field is commutative).